# Black screen on HP Pavilion zd7000

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an old HP Pavilion zd7000. It has a Pentium 4 | 2.8GHz | only 512 of RAM. The installation appeared to work fine, I can boot to a login screen but after entering my credentials it goes to a black screen with the mouse and completely unresponsive.  The video card is an old nVidia with 64MB of memory.

I suspect that it might be a driver issue but I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so I'm asking the questions.  Thank you all for your time and attention with this matter it is appreciated.

Comment: what does commands **unity --replace** and **startx** give? They are two independent commands but will give us a clue

Answer (score 0):

on 13.10 there is a bug. After you log in, there come a blackscreen.

Go to terminal by ctrg + alt + F1. log in and rm the file .Xauthority. Then reboot.